# Retrieving values from corresponding keys in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

The following only prints white lines. If this isn't the way to retrieve values from keys in Ruby, what is?

```
numbers = []

for i in 1..100 do
    hash = {
        :FizzBuzz => 1,
        :Prime => 3,
        :Fibonacci => 5
    }
    numbers << { i => hash }
end

numbers.each do |number|
    puts number[:Prime]
end
```

Note this is a MCVE, in the final application `1`, `3` and `5` will be function calls.

[Try it](https://repl.it/B7hE)

For those wondering what I was trying to do, the final (non-MCVE) result can be found [on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113564/52915).

Comment: It is not clear what your code is trying to accomplish in MCVE

Comment: @WandMaker I edited in a link to the final solution. It's not going to be much clearer than that I think, quite straightforward once it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first loop, `numbers` is an array like this:

```
[
  { 1 => { :FizzBuzz => 1, :Prime => 3, :Fibonacci => 5 } },
  { 2 => { :FizzBuzz => 1, :Prime => 3, :Fibonacci => 5 } },
  ...
  { 100 => { :FizzBuzz => 1, :Prime => 3, :Fibonacci => 5 } }
]
```

`number[:Prime]` is trying to fetch the `:Prime` element out of your first array element, but you only have the key `1`.

The end result is, you print empty lines, as nothing is found at each iteration. Hash access is okay; it is the logic of your code that is the problem (and you did not explain what you are trying to do precisely).

Comment: I ended up adding `1`, `2` etc as keys on the same level as `:FizzBuzz` et al. [Works like a charm](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113564/52915).

Answer (score 4):

Each `number` is a hash of this form:

```
{1=>{:FizzBuzz=>1, :Prime=>3, :Fibonacci=>5}}
```

which has a number as the sole key. When you look for a hash key that does not exist using `Hash#[]`, Ruby returns `nil`. And `puts nil` prints a blank line.

Indeed `Hash#[]` is the way to retrieve values from a hash.

Answer (score 2):

The keys of `number` are all integers (coming from `i`). The symbol `:Prime` is not a key. Therefore the results are all `nil`.